# How to get/set weights for a supervised model in tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'd like to change the weights of a supervised model but I get the same exact result after changing the weights.  What am I doing wrong?

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({...}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({...}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({...}));
model.compile({...});
model.fit({});

const result1 = model.predict(tf.tensor2d(...)).dataSync();

const newWeights = [];
model.layers.map((layer, i) => {
  newWeights[i] = []
  const weights = layer.getWeights();
  newWeights[i][0] = weights[0].arraySync()
  newWeights[i][1] = weights[1].arraySync()

  newWeights[i][0].map(tensor => tensor.map(x => {
    if (random(1) < 0.5) {
      return x + offset();
    }

    return x;
  })

  layer.setWeights([tf.tensor2d(newWeights[i][0], [newWeights[i][0].length, newWeights[i][0][0].length]), tf.tensor(newWeights[i][1])])
})

const result2 = model.predict(tf.tensor2d(...)).dataSync();
```

Code snippets:

```
const random = (max) => {
  return floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max), 2);
} 

const floor = (num, toDecimal) => {
  let  dec = Math.pow(10, toDecimal);
  return Number(Math.floor(num * dec) / dec);
}

const offset = () => {
  randomGaussian() * 0.5
}

let previous = false;
let y2 = 0;
const randomGaussian = (mean, sd) => {
  let y1, x1, x2, w;
  if (previous) {
    y1 = y2;
    previous = false;
  } else {
    do {
      x1 = random(2) - 1;
      x2 = random(2) - 1;
      w = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
    } while (w >= 1);
    w = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(w) / w);
    y1 = x1 * w;
    y2 = x2 * w;
    previous = true;
  }

  let m = mean || 0;
  let s = sd || 1;
  return y1 * s + m;
};
```

result1 === result2 but why?

Comment: Are you sure that `random(1)` is returning a result inferior to 0.5 ? Can you please add the code of `random` and `offset`, if possible making a snippet

Comment: @edkeveked I've added the code snippets, but yes I've confirmed that the tensor values are actually being mutated.  I know for sure that at the point of setting the weights, the values in my newWeights variable are indeed mutated and different.  Is there an apply function or something that I'm missing?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely that the new weights are identical to that of the first model.

**Example: Simple example to change weights of a model**

```js
(async() => {
const model = tf.sequential({
        layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [10]})]
    });
    model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
    for (let i = 1; i < 5 ; ++i) {
      const h = await model.fit(tf.ones([8, 10]), tf.ones([8, 1]), {
          batchSize: 4,
          epochs: 3
      });
      console.log("Loss after Epoch " + i + " : " + h.history.loss[0]);
    }
    
    const p = await model.predict(tf.zeros([1, 10]))
    p.print()
    const layers = model.layers

    layers[0].setWeights([tf.zeros([10, 1]), tf.zeros([1])])
    
    const q = await model.predict(tf.zeros([1, 10]))
    q.print()


})()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Issue of the code**

The `newWeights` created is not assigned to `newWeights`. `map` is not an in-place operator. The array returned by `map` should be assigned back to `newWeights`.

```
newWeights[i][0] = newWeights[i][0].map(tensor => tensor.map(x => {
    if (random(1) < 0.5) {
      return x + offset();
    }

    return x;
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the mapping issue the.