# tensorflow js how to load weights from another model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have two models `m1` and `m2`,

I would like to update the weights of model `m1` to be like `m2`,

In python with PyTorch it could be done with this line of code:

`m1.load_state_dict(m2.state_dict())`

but I couldn't find any information on the internet about it.

The only thing I found according to this documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load

is to save `m2` via local-storage for example and then to load it completely to `m1`, but it doesn't make sense to me to download and save it again just so I could update the weights.

Comment: Do both models have the same topology?

Comment: @Veeru I'm using tensorflow.js, is this code in python by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading the documentation better,

I found this:

```
m1.setWeights(m2.getWeights());
```

I also tried to `fit` one of them to see that it won't learn the other and it had no problem.

**Note** that they both should have the same structure, full example:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, inputShape: [8] }));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4 }));
model.compile({ optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });

const model2 = tf.sequential();
model2.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, inputShape: [8] }));
model2.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4 }));
model2.compile({ optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });

model2.setWeights(model.getWeights());

console.log(model.getWeights()[0].dataSync());
console.log(model2.getWeights()[0].dataSync());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Loading the weights of another model.

As indicated in the question, this can be done by saving the first model and then loading it as another model.

> it doesn't make sense to me to download and save it again just so I could update the weights.

It does not make sense to completely update a model 2 by a model 1 weights if both are not identical meaning they have the same topology. There is no method to clone a model directly and assign it to another variable. To do it, the model needs to be loaded as another model or its weights copied and assigned to another model with the same topology.

`model.getWeight` and `model.setWeights` can be used

```
model2.setWeights(model1.getWeights());
```

If the model 2 is to be updated partially , ie update the weights of some layers, it has been discussed in these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293937/weights-and-predictions-of-each-layer) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917450/how-to-get-set-weights-for-a-supervised-model-in-tensorflow-js)

Comment: They do have the same topology, it make sense because in some Deep Learning algorithm it is necessary ( such as Double DQL )